# Execute Observable one after another with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have two functions returning `Observables`.

```
this.markets$ = this.marketList();
this.buyersReviews$ = this.recentBuyersReviews();
```

And in my html I am using these two with `async` pipe as follows -

```
<div *ngIf="markets$ | async as market; else loadingOrErrorMarket">
.....
</div>

<section *ngIf="buyersReviews$ | async as review; else loadingOrErrorBuyersReviews">
....
</section>
```

Is there any way to call the `this.recentBuyersReviews()` when the `this.markets$` has completely loaded, and bind this to `this.buyersReviews$` and use the same in view with `async` pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, the rest stays the same -

```
this.buyersReviews$ = this.markets$.pipe(
    mergeMap(foo => this.recentBuyersReviews())
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="markets$ | async as market; else loadingOrErrorMarket">
        <div>
           .....
        </div>

        <section *ngIf="buyersReviews$ | async as review; else loadingOrErrorBuyersReviews">
                ....
        </section>
</ng-container>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-execute-observable-one-after-another-with-async-pipe)

Comment: Your method is working properly and gave you an 'up', but I dont want to move the buyerReviews into the market section. I was expecting a method with mergeMap or something like this.

Comment: @MithunSen the result is the same the markets and the buyers Reviews is different section but I put all of them inside `ng-container` 

Answer (score 1):

You could turn them into a singular stream:

```
  data$ = forkJoin({
    market: this.markets$, 
    buyers: this.buyers$
  })
```

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data></div>
```

Quick stackblitz demonstrating how to use:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8phnz

Comment:  your answer is toggle correct, I like forkjoin because it's easier to explan 

Comment: Yeah and the resulting data in your template is more predictable. You could merge it into a singular stream with `switchMap()` too but then you'll have to map it into a new object that you will also define the shape of. Works, but feels a bit more hacky; works well when the input from the first stream is required in the second stream.